# Is it possible to catch the arguments of a program?

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-arguments

I wwant to catch the command-line arguments of a program I use, so when I start test.exe with arguments `-debug` and `-console` I can see this arguments even if I don´t have the source code of the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wmic process where caption="test.exe" get commandline`
(you may of course also start `wmic` and then interactively query various properties of your system (processes included) if you wish so. `wmic /?` will show you options)

Edit: if you prefer GUI in win7 you should be able to select additional column (under view->select columns) named 'command line' (not sure exact wording) in Task Manager to show what you need;

And finally, you could hook up a debugger (***or anything posing as a debugger***, I used simple `cmd /k echo` as debugger target) via [Image Execution Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: +1, But I've read this is not reliable for some programs because the program is able to manipulate what appears there.

Comment: @dbenham Do you have a source? I'm not questioning it, just wanted to read on?

Comment: I just googled and found [How to clear a process command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3992786/1012053) on SO. It makes sense that a process may need to manipulate the stored command line. You probably don't want the password you typed into the command line to be easily accessible.

Comment: Here is a good discussion from Raymond Chen's BLOG *The Old New Thing*: [How do I get the command line of another process?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/11/25/9928372.aspx)

Comment: @dbenham Thanks - and see my edit, this will stop the process execution so it won't be able to modify it's command line.